# Reading all bytes from a file

Tags: c++, file-system

I'm basically trying to write a helper function that reads a whole file and returns the data and the number of bytes read.

Can you tell me if is correctly written and used?

```
#include <iostream>

static char * ReadAllBytes(const char * filename, int * read)
{
    ifstream ifs(filename, ios::binary|ios::ate);
    ifstream::pos_type pos = ifs.tellg();
    int length = pos;
    char *pChars = new char[length];
    ifs.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    ifs.read(pChars, length);
    ifs.close();
    *read = length;
    return pChars;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const char * filename = "polar00.map";
    int read ;
    char * pChars = ReadAllBytes(filename, &read);
    delete[] pChars;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A few things I would do differently:

```
static char * ReadAllBytes(const char * filename, int * read)
{
    ifstream ifs(filename, ios::binary|ios::ate);
    ifstream::pos_type pos = ifs.tellg();

    // What happens if the OS supports really big files.
    // It may be larger than 32 bits?
    // This will silently truncate the value/
    int length = pos;

    // Manuall memory management.
    // Not a good idea use a container/.
    char *pChars = new char[length];
    ifs.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    ifs.read(pChars, length);

    // No need to manually close.
    // When the stream goes out of scope it will close the file
    // automatically. Unless you are checking the close for errors
    // let the destructor do it.
    ifs.close();
    *read = length;
    return pChars;
}
```

How I would do it:

```
static std::vector<char> ReadAllBytes(char const* filename)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::binary|std::ios::ate);
    std::ifstream::pos_type pos = ifs.tellg();

    if (pos == 0) {
        return std::vector<char>{};
    }

    std::vector<char>  result(pos);

    ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    ifs.read(&result[0], pos);

    return result;
}
```

Note:

```
static std::vector<char> ReadAllBytes(char const* filename)
```

It may seem like an expensive copy operation. But in reality NRVO will make this an in-place operation so no copy will take place (just make sure you turn on optimizations). Alternatively pass it as a parameter:

```
static void ReadAllBytes(char const* filename, std::vector<char>& result)
```

Comment: I love this answer, never thought of referencing `vector[0]` to access the raw memory block underneath it.

Comment: This is very typical when using C++ containers and calling C code.

Comment: I typically used the `new unsigned char[size]` approach, which meant I had to ensure the cleanup afterwards. This is much nicer.

Comment: Thank you, it's much simpler and cleaner. I thought of using array<char> but since it is (from what I've read) allocated on the stack it was not a good idea as my data wouldn't necessarily be small. Well, I've forgot to apply this again : "premature optimization is the root of all evil" ...

Comment: An alternative to `&vector[0]` is [`vector.data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data).

Comment: What about error checking. Both opening and reading might fail.

Comment: @Zitrax: My answer is based on the context of the original question where no error checking is done. In real code you would do error checking, but there is not enough context for me to add it here as it will depend on how and where this code is used.

Comment: In C++11, you can also get to the vector's memory by calling `vector.data()`.

Comment: You actually can't use `tellg()` for the size of a file; it only kind-maybe-sometimes works. See the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984956/tellg-function-give-wrong-size-of-file/22986486#22986486).

Comment: @einpoklum In reality this is going to work as expected in almost all situations. If you are worried about portability (which on non standard or minor distributions can be an issue) you can easily set up unit test to validate the functionality works as expected (autotools are your friends learn to use them so you can validate standard behaviors of libraries). I agree with the link that theoretically there may be an issue.

Comment: But the proposed solution looks a bit hacky. I would have to test it but would not ignore() force a full scan of the file to reach the end? Also the suggested solution also suffers from the same problem suggested of `tellg()` when the file is opened in "Text Mode". I think a better solution may be to ask the filesystem for the size.

Comment: @einpoklum You will also note that author also makes the same point I do: `in practice, on Unix systems, the value returned will be the offset in bytes from the beginning of the file, and under Windows, it will be the offset from the beginning of the file for files opened in binary mode.`

Comment: Do NOT use `&vector[0]` if it may be empty.

Comment: Well, vector[0] is non-existent in an empty vector so accessing it seems to be UB; and debugging implementations may throw an exception for that. And I remember having problems with it in the past.

Comment: @HansOlsson: No. The standard guarantees you can take the address of one past the end.

Comment: The problem is that taking the address of doesn't cancel the dereference in terms of UB and error checking. I used to think that myself - and got problems and thus changed to using .data and similar constructs that avoid this. Would you write &*((int*)(0)) ?

Comment: A Principal Engineer at Microsoft working on compilers thinks differently in the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485496/how-to-get-stdvector-pointer-to-the-raw-data

Comment: @HansOlsson I don't think we are going to persuade each other that we are wrong. I am confident in my reading of the standard. You have a firm stand on your position further discussion seems to be pointless.

Comment: The final sentence (for .data() ) is "The advantage of this member function is that it is okay to call it even if the container is empty." that's a pretty direct indication that &something[0] that is specifically stated to work for non-empty vector doesn't work for empty ones. It is also directly stated that it produces undefined results in item 16 in Scott Meyers "Effective STL" 
So, at least I hope to convince some to be more careful.

Comment: @HansOlsson: [n4892](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/n4892.pdf) S`ection: 22.3.11.4 Data [vector.data]` This covers the fuction: `constexpr T* data() noexcept;` The requirement of this function is: `Returns: A pointer such that [data(), data() + size()) is a valid range.` There is no precondition on it not being empty. This has probably been updated since Scott M wrote his book.

Comment: The point: The advantage of using `&something[0]` is that it works for all contiguous containers (and consistency is very important to maintainable code). Which includes C-Arrays; where `data()` does not work. And though `&something[0]` was not always guaranteed to work (the update to the standard was made in C++14) it worked in practice on all major compilers since C++11 (which was why the standard update was so simple).

Comment: Don't use &vector[0] for possibly empty data:
The function std::vector::data() was added explicitly because &something[0]  gave UB for empty vectors (name chosen based on as std::array that can be used for C-style arrays). http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#464
Thus I don't see that my other comments are needed.

The assumption that &something[0] is valid hinges on the assumption that taking the address of a non-dereferencable iterator is ok. However, only iterators in the range [begin,end) are defined as dereferencable in 24.2.1§5, in this case the range is empty

Comment: Except that for an empty vector, where begin()==end() and thus *begin() is not valid as begin() is not dereferenceable, or to quote about end() "Such a value is called a past-the-end value. Values of an iterator i for which the expression *i is defined are called dereferenceable. The library never assumes that past-the-end values are dereferenceable." As for compilers: g++ -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG fails on it as does Visual Studio 2019 debug-builds. So, if you don't care about empty vectors, or don't care about running your code with a debugger it may work; but that ends my interaction here.

Comment: The standard seem to be making the same "mistake": [iterator.iterators] table 94: Defines that `operator*` for iterator as "`*r` Requires: r is dereferenceable."                 So, if you want code that works even for empty vectors, especially in debug-builds use `.data()` for vector. And that finally ends my interaction.

Comment: @HansOlsson You are correct: **I was wrong**. You made me re-read all the way down to the definition of `contiguous_iterator Concept`. Getting the address for an iterator of one past the end is only defined if there exists a dereferencable iterator into the container. With an empty vector this does not exist so as you pointed out this is UB for empty vectors.

Answer (score 3):

## Missing error checking

Both your code and the code from Martin York's answer don't perform any error checking. Things can go wrong both when *opening* a file (it might not exist, you might not have the right permissions, and so on), and when *reading* from a file (less likely at this point, but read errors are still possible). You want to ensure two things:

- Your program doesn't crash while trying to read a file.
- Any errors are not silently ignored, as this might cause your program to give incorrect results without you knowing it.

I recommend checking that `ifs.eof() == true` after reading all the data. If it's not, then you didn't succesfully reach the end of the file, and then report the error in some way; for example, `throw` an exception or use a [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) for the return value.

`tellg()` will return `-1` in case of an error. When trying to allocate memory for the result, that `-1` might be cast to an unsigned `std::size_t` and become a huge number, causing the memory allocation to fail. This might cause your program to crash. So check the return value of `tellg()` before using it.

Answer (score 3):

I would amend [Martin York's answer](/a/22907/75307):

- use `std::filesystem::path` (standard as of C++17; part of Boost before that) instead of `std::string` for the parameter.
- use `vector::data` instead of taking the address of the first element.

I'm also a little worried about using `ate` mode but then seeking back to the beginning.  Is this guaranteed to only jump back to the end on any *write* operation, but allow me to read from any position?  Also, what if the file is read-only?  I'd rather open for reading only, not specify that I'll be writing to the end because I don't need write access at all!

Reading the docs, I see that `ate` just seeks right after opening, as distinct from `app` which forces writes on the end (even though it stands for *append to end*).  It can be combined with other flags without otherwise affecting the meaning.  So, use

`std::ios::in|std::ios::binary|std::ios::ate`

Comment: Don't be too harsh on that first point - that `std::filesystem` didn't exist in 2013.  It's a good suggestion for updating to make it more type-safe in modern contexts, though.  :-)

Comment: And `std::ios::ate` ("open __at e__ ​nd") doesn't imply writing at all - and `std::ifstream` constructor always includes `std::ios::in`, so no need to redundantly specify that.

Answer (score 2):

I would wrap the native memory-mapped file functionality instead. It’s available on all major platforms. In all cases it will be more efficient than any “read the whole file” code would be. If you absolutely need to keep the file’s contents yet close the file, you can then initialize a vector from the memory-mapped byte range, and close the range afterwards. It will still be faster and less cumbersome than reading the file.

Typically, you won’t have to bother with errors once the file is open and mapped: read errors become page faults. You can of course trap those if needed, but if there’s no viable way for the application to proceed if the file cannot be read after successfully mapping it, then terminating is a good option. But, to be flexible, I’d ensure that while the file is mapped, any I/O errors that turned into page faults get caught and handled appropriately per the preference of the user of your code.

Comment: Boost provides an abstraction of memory-mapped files, so if that's available to you, there's no need to write your own code for the various APIs.

Comment: On 32-bit systems you can only map about 2 GB this way. Also, for small files, this might actually be less efficient, as setting up the page tables and handling the initial page faults when accessing the mapped range for the first time isn't free.

Comment: If the normal handle-based file I/O is implemented in terms of memory mapping for local files, then the page faults and page tables etc. is not any worse than it does anyway.  The big deal is the overhead of keeping an open file if it's a small amount of data.

Comment: If the file to be slurped is not on the local file system, memory mapping may not work or be very inefficient.  So you need a fallback for reading remote files anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer constructs the `std::vector` in a way that zero-fills all the bytes before overwriting them.

```cpp
std::vector<char> result(pos);
```

That seems to me like it could be wasteful, but I admit I haven't measured the performance, and that operation is probably super-fast. However, if you want to avoid it, you can use the [`resize_and_overwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize_and_overwrite) member function in `std::basic_string`. Unfortunately I don't see a similar function for `std::vector`. Here's an example, with some error checking as suggested by other answers.

```cpp
using namespace std;

string read_all(const filesystem::path &file_path)
{
    ifstream ifs(file_path, ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
    auto pos = ifs.tellg();
    if (pos == -1) {
        throw runtime_error("read_all: failed to open");
    }
    
    string result;
    if (pos == 0) {
        return result;
    }

    ifs.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    result.resize_and_overwrite(pos, [&](char *ptr, int n) {
        ifs.read(ptr, pos);
        return pos;
    });
    
    if (!ifs.good()) {
        throw runtime_error("read_all: failed to read to as expected");
    }

    return result;
}
```